# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UIKit' could not be found when doing a CI build

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uikit

UIKit will build in my CI build in my IOS project in my solution but will not build in my common project noted here,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfo79.png)

it gives me the error noted above. Any idea why. I need this to do alerts on my ipone because the App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert and the PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new PopupPage()); utilizing the Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage are not working, but I know the alerts in the UIKit work as they work on another IOS app that I have.

Oh, and by the way, this builds locally, just not on my CI build

Here is my yaml for the CI build, very basic

steps:
- task: XamariniOS@2
displayName: 'Build Solution '
inputs:
solutionFile: MileageManagerForms.sln
configuration: 'Ad-Hoc'
clean: true
workingDirectory: MileageManagerForms/MileageManagerForms.iOS

Comment: UIKit is an iOS class.  You cannot use it in a common project, which is (probably) a .NET Core project.  If you want to use platform specific code in a common project, use DependencyService or a custom renderer.   OR, you could figure out why the other options are not working

Comment: *" this builds locally, just not on my CI build"* - It shouldn't - that's a messy practice, that will likely cause maintenance problems long-term. I recommend removing all references to any iOS namespaces or dlls, from your common project. Find out what that breaks, then fix it WITHOUT adding back in those namespaces/references/dlls. As Jason suggests, that means the common project must make use of something that is provided by the iOS project. I would make an iOS custom renderer for each type of UI control.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding DependencyService, because when I create an interface on my shared project to do this per examples, I need to define AlertUIVIew so that can come back from my IOS project and that requires UIKIt so it won't work. Can you please give me a little example of how I would do this?

Comment: For iOS you typically get better results if you build the csproj file of the iOS project rather than the sln file. Or create a sln file that only has the iOS and shared projects in it.

Comment: I found this link which showed me how to do it and it is working. Thanks to all for answering. https://hiranpeiriscom.wordpress.com/2017/02/18/what-is-a-dependency-service-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: However, not even these alerts show up on my iPhone. The 2 methods I mentioned above and the UIAlertVIew I just implemented with the UIKit, none of them display the popup. Is there something special I need to do on the iPhone to get those to display? What am I missing? All 3 display and function properly on the simulator just not on my phone. My code to display the popup is just like the code in the link I referenced above. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `UIKit` assembly reference correctly.

Per [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) :

A type or namespace that is used in the program was not found. You might have forgotten to reference (-reference) the assembly that contains the type, or you might not have added the required using directive. Or, there might be an issue with the assembly you are trying to reference.

Use UIAlertControllerStyle to indicate the type of alert to display.These alerts types are:

```
•   UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet
•   UIAlertControllerStyleAlert
```

The code to display a simple alert is as follows:

```
okayButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

    //Create Alert
    var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create ("Title", "The message", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    //Add Action
    okAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

    // Present Alert
    PresentViewController (okAlertController, true, null);
};
```

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/alerts

**Update:**
There is a workaround that use [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to set the alert on the iOS project.

1.Create an interface in our shared package.

```
public interface IMessage
{
    void LongAlert(string message);
    void ShortAlert(string message);
}
```

2.In iOS project,we should implement it.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageIOS))]
namespace Your.Namespace
{
      public class MessageIOS : IMessage
    {
        const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

        NSTimer alertDelay;
        UIAlertController alert;

        public void LongAlert(string message)
       {
           ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
       }
        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
           ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
       {
           alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
          {
               dismissMessage();
          });
           alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }

    void dismissMessage()
    {
        if (alert != null)
        {
            alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
        }
        if (alertDelay != null)
        {
            alertDelay.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The you can get the alert service in anywhere in our project.

```
DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShortAlert(string message); 
DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert(string message);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, it is much appreciated, however, I am not using ViewControllers on my front-end code, it is all running in my common project in Views and view models I am using DependencyService from my common project to set the alert on the IOS project, but that is all it does, shows the alert and goes back to the common project. I can't even fathom how I could use a view controller in this process. Is there another way to handle this with the architecture I am using? Any ideas at all?

Comment: Hi Steve, I've updated it.Please manage to get it worked!Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, just like all the other methods for trying to get a popup to open, this one works in the simulator, but not on my iPhone. I would like to show my exact code, which is pretty much like yours, but I can't see how to do that in this little comment box. I have tried 4 different methods, they all work in the simulator, but none on my iphone. Let me know if there is a way I can show my code for you to take a look at. Thanks so much!

Comment: Since this conversation has completely gone away from the original question, I have decided to open a new question about alerts specifically. Please see item with this title, 
Cannot get Alerts to show on iPhone no matter what way I code it and I have tried 4 different ways, if you are interested in this topic. Thank you!

Comment: May I know what Visual Studio version you are using?